# Joomla, Wordpress - что быстрее?

Tags: cms, joomla, php, wordpress

Что на Ваш взгляд быстрее *joomla* или *WP*? И много ли запросов к БД выполняет *joomla* и *WP*? А то стоит у меня *джумла*, без лишних плагинов, хостер порой глючит, я ему пишу - он говорит, что нужно сайт оптимизировать в плане запросов к БД. По мне *джумла* быстрее *WP*. Я уж не знаю, что там в в *WP* грузится, но порой на локалке открывается еле-еле, а после только перегружать компьютер надо, чтобы загрузился сайт на *WP*, причём локально. С джумлой меньше проблем, зато *WP* мне кажется удобнее для "юзверя". С удовольствием выслушаю вашу критику и не критику, сравнение данных двигателей.

**P.S.:** Ставлю пальцы всем, кто хорошо ответит

Comment: Пришел @Expert и все художество испортил. =(
Кстати, раз уж отредактировали, почему не изменили комментарий в P.S.? Получилось, что @mctrane захотел проиндексировать слова постскриптум?!

Comment: Пришлось убрать этот пс =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Быстрее* вордпресс. Но номинально, в джумле надо сделать меньше телодвижений, чтобы достичь большего числа свистелок и рюшечек, так как модулей там более 100500. А вообще, сравнивать их странно. Может, у меня устаревшие данные, конечно, но для меня это CMS-ка под совершенно разные задачи.

Comment: Задачи разные, но есть и общие задачи. Некоторые сайты можно сделать одинаково удобно как на joomla, так и на wordpress.

Comment: Если можно сделать одинаково удобно, используйте WP.